# Did Marvel Comics abort plans for greater integration into comic continuity of Marvelman (Miracleman) after getting the rights 2009-2013?

Tags: marvel, captain-marvel, miracleman

Reference Marvel Comics crusade to obtain clear ownership of Marvelman & Miracleman 2009-2013, [first obtaining rights to Marvelman from Mick Anglo](https://www.google.com/amp/s/geeksofdoom.com/2009/07/24/sdcc-marvel-acquires-rights-to-marvel-man%3famp) and [then acquiring rights to Eclipse Comics’ Miracleman (the “Moore/Gaiman stories”)](https://www.comicsbeat.com/marvel-now-owns-miracleman-the-trademark/). This crusade concluded with a comics event, debuted at 2013 NYCC: [Marvelman Returns!](https://www.comicsbeat.com/miracleman-is-back-in-january-and-here-are-the-variant-covers/?amp)

This was the start of Marvel Comics’ *Marvelman* series, reprinting the Eclipse series and then having Gaiman pen new stories, along with publishing the new Marvel Comics’ *Marvelman Classic* books which reprinted the original Anglo stories.

Also, reference the evolution of the original Captain Marvel / Ms. Marvel costume aesthetic from its inception to Marvel’s post-Marvelman 2013 reboot which remains the current aesthetic.

### Captain Marvel:

[image: Original Marvel]

### Ms. Marvel:

[image: Ms. Marvel]

### Marvelman (Miracleman):

[image: Marvelman]

### Post-Marvelman Captain Marvel 2013 Reboot

And then Marvel’s post-Marvelman 2013 Captain Marvel reboot:

[image: Capt. Reboot]
[image: Capt. Marvel (film)]

### Whattup with that costume change?!?

The aesthetic evolution is pretty strong in its own right. But then, at the same time, Marvel was also planning for its major Secret Wars reboot which included some very interesting roles. Starbrand was brought in to join the Avengers. As was more strangely Hyperion, who always felt shoehorned in.

As if there was an original nuclear-based Superman that Marvel may otherwise have intended to use, and then changed plans midstream.

Was Marvelman supposed to play a larger role in Marvel’s comic universe beyond just reprinting older stories and adding a few new Gaiman ones? Was (s)he supposed to be a flagship character and an Avenger in post 2013 storylines? Is the move to “Marvelman” type aesthetic just a coincidence?